# Start an aws ec2 machine with elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

In aws ec2 machines,is there a way to start up an instance and tell it to use an Elastic IP?
Perhaps using user data or something?

Assigning IP to an aws ec2 machine after launch is pretty simple,following the amazon docs,but I would like to launch a machine with the elastic ip.
i.e) While the machine is launches itself, it should be assigned with the IP.

Someone has asked this in the aws support forum 10 years ago, the thread has no solution though.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=20927

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this can be done:

- Create a **Network Interface**
- Attach the **Elastic IP** to the Network Interface
- When launching the Amazon EC2 instance, **specify the Network Interface** to use (that is, the one created earlier)

The instance will then be **launched with the Elastic IP address**.

There does *not* appear to be a way to do this totally within the `RunInstances` command. Only a PublicIP address can be requested, which is temporary and is not an Elastic IP address.

Comment: What would happen if another instance in the same interface is already assigned that public IP?

Comment: I suspect that, if the Elastic IP address has been configured with the **Reassociation** attribute, then it will be detached from the existing resource and attached to the new instance.